# How to find the SMTP username of wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can retrive site admin mail using

```
get_bloginfo('admin_mail')
```

i want to retrive the username associated with SMTP setting.
How this can be done?
I can get the username associated with the admin email by using `get_user_by()`  but i need username associated with smtp settings.

Comment: The password could literally be stored anywhere, and it might depend on a plugin, too. I'd start by looking a wp-config.php, but if you are using an SMTP plugin I'd look there, too

Comment: if you use wp_mail - For this function to work, the settings SMTP and smtp_port (default: 25) need to be set in your php.ini file. Read more about wp_mail() here - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/ If you use plugin check your database for saved settings or ask dev.